# Power BI: How to show previous result when no result found in a cumulative sum

Tags: matrix, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, cumulative-sum

Hope you could help me with the following. I'm trying to show a cumulative sum of HC per month.

HC results each month can be either +1, +2, -1, -2 etc... or nothing (no entry).

Looking at the screenshot, for example CDM, we have 5 HC in 2020-11 and there are no changes until 2021-3 where we have an increase of +1HC. I want to show the 5 HC throughout all the months in between these 2 dates.

[image: screenshot]

this is the meassure I'm using:

Cumulative HC View =
CALCULATE(
SUM(CPM[HC]),
FILTER(ALL(CPM[Month]),CPM[Month]<=MAX(CPM[Month])))

any ideas?
thank you!
Enric

Comment: hi, in CPM table, do you have full month? for example, for CDM, do you have each month even it's 0 (2020-12,2021-1,2021-2 are blank or 0 but you have these rows of CDM in table)?

Comment: No, I dont't... in case there is no action that particular month doesn't appear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Create Calendar table:**

```
Calendar = 
FILTER(
CALENDAR(FIRSTDATE('CPM'[Month]),LASTDATE('CPM'[Month])),
DAY([Date])=1)
```

**2. Calculate [HC measure] and [Index column] in CPM table:**

```
HC Measure = SUM(CPM[HC])

Index Column= [Month]&[Geo]
```

**3. Create new table:**

```
Table = ADDCOLUMNS(
UNION( ADDCOLUMNS('Calendar',"Geo","CDM"),
    ADDCOLUMNS('Calendar',"Geo","CERTA"),
    ADDCOLUMNS('Calendar',"Geo","Claims"),
    ADDCOLUMNS('Calendar',"Geo","Control Tower")),
"Index",[Date]&[Geo])
```

**4. Set relationship in Model view:**

[image]

**5. Calculate columns in new table:**

```
HC = CALCULATE([HC Measure])

Cumulative HC View = 
SUMX(FILTER(ALL('Table'),
    [Date]<=EARLIER('Table'[Date])&&
    [Geo]=EARLIER('Table'[Geo])),
    'Table'[HC])
```

[image]

**6. Create table visual with columns in new table:**

[image]

Comment: wow! thank you! let me follow the steps! first thing I encountered is the following:
in step 2 I get this error: 
The value for 'Month' cannot be determined. Either the column doesn't exist, or there is no current row for this column".

Comment: do you have [Month] in CPM table? or screenshot for this question with table view so i can see

Comment: indeed it's there. I tried adding the table name but still the same error. See attached including the table columns 
<img src="https://www.viajablog.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/Capture3.jpg"> (not sure how to upload images in the comment...)

Comment: oh they are two things. HC measure is a measure, Index column is a column.

Comment: Please mark this answer if helps you. (in the right buttons)